# HTML frame problem

Tags: html

This is the code of the main page:

```
<frameset cols="12%,19%,69%" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO" border="0" name="mainframeset">
  <frame src="1.html" name="maoinFrame" scrolling="no">
<frame src="2.html" name="mainFrame" scrolling="yes" noresize="resize" >
  <frame src="3.html" name="bottomFrame" >
</frameset>
```

`1.html` is a blank page. `2.html` has this link:

```
<a href="link.html" target="mainframeset">Home</a>
```

`3.html` is another page.  When I click the home link in the page I need to open the (`link.html`) in the current window with no frames. At the moment it opens the page in a new window.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470651/removing-html-frames

Comment: Side note - Your frame tags are not being properly closed.

Comment: Your second frame has `name="maoinFrame"`. Did you mean `name="mainFrame"`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `target="_top"` like this:

```
<a href="link.html" target="_top">yourtext</a>
```